# hide Web Start "verifying application" progress dialog when no update

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp

Each time we launch our Java Web Start application an ugly "verifying application" progress dialog shows. Is it possible to hide this when the application has no updates?

I know I can add "update check='background'" to the JNLP file but it is absolutely necessary that the client gets updated when an update is available. (Because server and client are tightly coupled through the domain model).

Comment: Not an answer, but if I allow offline and use shortcut online="false" this dialog does disappear and instead a slightly less ugly "Java 7 Oracle..." dialog shortly appears. To update the user can run the application from the browser.

Comment: Perhaps a custom progress indicator could help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/customProgressIndicatorForAppln.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to hide this when the application has no updates?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom progress indicator as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/customizeRIALoadingExperience.html).
It replaces the default progress dialog.

Furthermore, somehow it isn't opened when the application has no update which solves my problem.